# Change system properties(name) under linux

Tags: cpu

What I wondering can I change somehow under linux( ubuntu / redhat ) the name of processor like in windows by registry edition?
What I mean is currently when I make `cat /proc/cpuinfo` I got

```
....snip....
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz
....more snip....
```

So can I change model name or vendor_id to something else?

As I know in windows I can change it under

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is it that you are trying to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: Since I know that is possible on windows I wondering if is also possible in Linux.

Comment: `/proc/cpuinfo` is a pesudo-file that reads the data out of the kernel.  I doubt they're an interface to enable userspace apps to change the data that is delivered by that file.